# Magento2 : sales order grid add new column with it's values

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-grid

when order placed at that time in admin sales order check that there is a gift option available or not if it is available that dispaly "yes" in order grid column else display "no".

please see attachments for more.

please share any suggestion if you have.

1) image where gift option available

[image: gift option available here]

2) image where display "yes" in grid
[image]

thanks

Comment: Please check last comment of Answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a UI component sales_order_grid.xml under

> [Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

and add the following code to your **sales_order_grid.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="export_status" class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Giftstatus">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gift Option</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Then created the UI class under

> [Vendor]/[Module]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Giftstatus.php

add the following code to your **Giftstatus.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Giftstatus extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $status = $order->getData("gift_message_id");

                if($status){
                    $message = 'Yes';
                }
                else{
                    $message = 'No';
                }

                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $message;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,  i did the same but in result only get "No". i have changed "gift_message_id" to "gift_message_available" but not working it. Is there anything else need to change there ?

Comment: Gift_message_id is only available if order contains gift message. Are you using gift option per order or per item? If using per order then it should work.

Comment: Also check the sales_order table if your order contains the gift message id or not

Comment: after var_dump() order data i got this name "gift_message_available" but his one is also not working.

Comment: i am using gift option per order.

Comment: Which magento version? Check the order table you will definitely get the gift_message_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80052/discussion-between-sarfaraj-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: This is work for when "Gift Option" send / added For whole cart so it's working fine for it. like admin->stores->cofiguration->sales->gift option->select gift option per order 
But from admin->stores->cofiguration->sales->gift option->select gift option per product item it will not work.

Comment: That is different. I need to check that for product wise

Comment: i checked it from both site admin and frontend for per product item  and per order so it's only work for per order instead of per product item gift message.

Comment: @SukumarGorai can you help me if I want to add same field in filter too as a select option?